# Meteorjs link social media accounts

Tags: meteor

I'm attempting to use the **bozhao:link-accounts** package from Atmosphere, but with no luck. Rather than linking the accounts, it is creating additional accounts. Here is what my implementation looks like:

PACKAGES ADDED:
meteor add accounts-facebook
meteor add accounts-twitter
meteor add bozhao:link-accounts
meteor add service-configuration

```html
<!--/client/signIn.html-->
<template name="signInTmpl">
  <button class="btn btn-facebook">Sign in with Facebook</button>  
</template>

<!--/client/linkTweets.html-->
<template name="linkTweetsTmpl">
  <button class="btn btn-twitter">Connect Twitter Account</button>
</template>
```

```js
//client/signIn.js
Template.siginInTmpl.events({
  'click .btn-facebook': function() {
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({requestPermissions: ['email']}, function(err) {
    //Do if conditional ... 
     }) 
   }
})

//client/linkTweets.js
Template.linkTweetsTmpl.events({
  'click .btn-twitter': function() {
    Meteor.linkWithTwitter(function(err) {
    //Do if conditional ... 
     }) 
   }
})

//server/accounts.js
var createServiceConfiguration;

createServiceConfiguration = function(service, clientId, secret) {
  var config;
  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
    service: service
  });
  config = {
    generic: {
      service: service,
      clientId: clientId,
      secret: secret
    },
    instagram: {
      service: service,
      clientId: clientId,
      scope: 'basic',
      secret: secret,
      loginStyle: "redirect"
    },
    facebook: {
      service: service,
      appId: clientId,
      secret: secret,
      loginStyle: "redirect"
    },
    twitter: {
      service: service,
      consumerKey: clientId,
      secret: secret,
      loginStyle: "redirect"
    }
  };
  switch (service) {
    case 'instagram':
      return ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert(config.instagram);
    case 'facebook':
      return ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert(config.facebook);
    case 'twitter':
      return ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert(config.twitter);
    default:
      return ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert(config.generic);
  }
};
//DEV KEYS
createServiceConfiguration('instagram', 'api-key', 'api-secret')
createServiceConfiguration('facebook', 'api-key', 'api-secret')
createServiceConfiguration('twitter', 'api-key', 'api-secret')
createServiceConfiguration('google', 'api-key', 'api-secret')
```

I successfully sign in with Facebook and when I click on the "Connect Twitter Button" it goes through the authorisation sequence fine, but then creates another account altogether.

Comment: have you checked out https://atmospherejs.com/splendido/accounts-meld instead?

Comment: Thanks at @Xinzz that package works great. A few things I'll need to refine, but it looks very comprehensive for my needs. Thanks once again.

Comment: I added the comment as an answer as well. Feel free to upvote/mark as correct for others who need help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `https://atmospherejs.com/splendido/accounts-meld` instead to do what you want. The documentation is pretty self explanatory and it supports a wide range of account melding configurations.